# Java Regular Expression to Handle Strings Contains Next Line

Tags: java, regex

I have a text like this

```
Customer Owned 03/26 04/25 0.00
Modem
```

Here Modem is in Next line

Now i need to write the data into spreadsheet as

Customer Owned Modem    03/26 04/25   0.00

I wrote a regex as

```
([a-zA-Z = ]*) ([[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} ]*) (-?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+)
```

I am getting the description as "Customer Owned" instead of "Customer Owned Modem". Is there any way to handle through Regex?

Comment: Maybe you can do a first pass over it and get rid of the newlines between the first and the second line?  Then your regex will work as you want.

Comment: Please show how you are using this in code, as that will help determine how you need to apply your pattern modifier to make it multi-line. Even if this was multi-line, however, you don't have a subpattern to capture the text after the decimal number portion of the string.

Comment: show us the full code you use

Comment: if your text file is well structured as above I would highly recommend writing simple code to break strings etc to parse the file. Regexps are good but are relatively hard to maintain. A Parser which uses simple string functions would be much easier to understand to anyone who might eventually inherit your code.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Okay.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this regex:

```
([A-Za-z ]+)([^A-Za-z]+)[\r\n]*([A-Za-z]+)
```

And replace by:

```
\1\3 \2
```

Here's a [demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/tB4xR9) using your example.

Answer (score 0):

To match newline you can try \r?\n

Update your regex accordingly to include newline as well as the text thereafter

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following to your regular expression.  This will detect an end of line on all platforms and capture the following line in the last group.  You can then concatenate group 1 and the last group together.

`(?:\n|\r|\n\r|\r\n)([a-zA-Z = ]*)$`